# how to allow only POST and GET http verb for methods of implicit controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have a implicit Controller like this :

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function getShow($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

And in Routes I write this:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

We know that `users/show` responds if only user request it via **GET** http request.

but if I want it responds only to GET and POST (and not other methods like PUT, DELETE ,... ) How can I do that?

Of course we know that we can use `any` prefix for above method but it responds to all http method. like this :

```
class UserController extends Controller
    {

        public function anyShow($id)
        {
            //
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly? If you don't implement put...() or delete...() methods – they won't work anyway. If your implicit controller only got get and post methods – only get and post routes will work. I don't see any problem or it's not formulated informative enough?

Comment: I just want a method that responds to GET and POST method. users could not send data to that via other http methods.

Comment: So, create getSomething() and postSomething() methods and don't implement any other methods. As simple as that?

Comment: Yes, that is correct and simplest method that I did not think about it.please  rewrite your comment as an answer that I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your implicit controller only contains GET and POST (prefixed) methods – no other methods will work, so there is no need to worry.

Eg. if you have:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getShow($id)
    {
    }

    public function postShow($id)
    {
    }
}
```

Laravel will only allow 'GET /show' and 'POST /show'.

Please however note that Laravel is abandoning implicit controllers soon, because, even though they offer simplicity, implicit controllers introduce a number of disadvantages. [This article](https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2013/07/23/beware-the-route-to-evil/) has a good analysis.